# Node/Express: Session Sharing between Browser and Server

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue - although I might have googled using the wrong questions.

I'm building a react app with server-side rendering. There is also another server which handles the entire API.

**Here's the scenario I need to get working:**

1. Initial website request initiated from user.
2. UI server loads the user from another API server
3. UI server then pre-renders all react components including the fetched user and sends it to the user
4. React component in browser needs to be able to fetch updated user information (from the api server, not the UI server)

So the problem is that I need to share the same session ID between the browser and the UI server.

**I imagine it would work like this.**

1. UI server requests user from API server.
2. UI server remembers session id from initial call and sets the cookie
3. Browser uses the set cookie for all future api requests and page refreshes

Is this achievable?

Comment: Not clear on your architecture here. When you say you're communicating with another server from the client, what does that mean? Can you just proxy to that other server through the server that actually serves up the page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) instead of cookies. You can share the token in all of your services. It is the best way to authenticate user to use different apis at the same time.

Here is [detailed tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) for Node/Express